# Which IDE supports gtpl (groovy templates)?

Tags: groovy, ide

So, IntelliJ/Idea can't seem to find time to support Groovy's templating language ([IDEA-96594](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96594)) - especially [markuptemplateengine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_the_markuptemplateengine).

Which IDE supports GTPL's? Are there any?

Answer (score -2):

just renaming "*.gtpl" to "*.gsp" will do the trick

Comment: you can also modify web.xml & sitemesh3.xml in that direction (i.e. gsp)

Comment: Well. Groovy Server Pages (gsp) and Groovy template language is far from identical - so no. That does not do the trick. IntelliJ has excellent gsp support. Look at the link above, and you'll see what I mean.